# A group homomorphism $\phi : G\to H$. Then $\phi[G]$ is abelian iff $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in \ker(\phi)$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, group-homomorphism

From *A First Course In Abstract Algebra* by John B. Fraleigh, 7th edition. Section 13, problem 50.

Let $\phi: G\to H$ be a group homomorphism. Show that $\phi[G]$ is abelian if and only if for all $x,y \in G$, we have $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in\ker(\phi)$.

[Proof moved to answer]

Comment: Your proof seems good.

Comment: @GAVD Awesome! Do you suppose I should edit it then and post the proof separately as an answer?

Comment: I agree, it looks solid. Seems reasonable to move the proof to an answer so it can be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\phi[G]$ is abelian, and let $e^{\prime}$ be the identity element of H.

We have $\phi(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=\phi(x)\phi(y)\phi(x^{-1})\phi(y^{-1})$. Since $\phi(a^{-1})=\phi(a)^{-1}$, we then have $\phi(x)\phi(y)\phi(x)^{-1}\phi(y)^{-1}$. Since $\phi[G]$ is abelian, we can rearrange this to obtain $\phi(x)\phi(x)^{-1}\phi(y)\phi(y)^{-1}=e^{\prime}e^{\prime}=e^{\prime}$. Thus, $\phi(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=e^{\prime}$, thus $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in Ker(\phi)$.

Now, suppose that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in Ker(\phi)$. Then, $\phi(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=e^\prime$. By the homomorphism property, then, $\phi(x)\phi(y)\phi(x^{-1})\phi(y^{-1})=e^{\prime}$. Again, inverses are preserved, so we have $\phi(x)\phi(y)\phi(x)^{-1}\phi(y)^{-1}=e^{\prime}$.

But, $\phi(x)^{-1}\phi(y)^{-1}=(\phi(y)\phi(x))^{-1}$, so multiplying the last equation above on the right by $(\phi(y)\phi(x))$ we obtain

$\phi(x)\phi(y)=\phi(y)\phi(x)$, therefore $\phi[G]$ is abelian.

This completes the proof.